# How to differentiate "Note" and "Mail" item in Lotus notes? Using Domino.dll

Tags: c#, email, lotus-notes, interop-domino

I have a Nsf file in which in one of folder there are some mail and notes items.

I am differentiating each item with "form" property.
In case of mails form type is "memo" but in above scenario Notes "form" type is again "memo"

How can i differentiate these two items?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

Using the "form" item is not a safe way to distinguish emails from other "documents". In fact, a Notes data store does not really distinguish where a document came from - whether from a delivered email or a created document. However, you can use the fields RouteTimes and RouteServers to take a pretty good guess as to whether a given document was initiated from an email message. (The existence of either field will generally mean the document was delivered by the mail router).

Comment: Thanx Ed.But in my Nsf Sample i am getting "" value of RouteTimes and RouteServers for both Notes and mail.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the fields, I think the best way is to compare `$` fields because they are usually reserved for internal use and should not be updated without a good reason. Therefore they are the most accurate fields of a form.

Check `$MessageID`, `$MIMETrack` or `$UpdatedBy`. This last one should be used with care but it should contains the mail server(s) if it is a mail.

Answer (score 0):

In LN you can mock a the mail template in a note. So there is no *sure* way to distinguish a note from a mail UNLESS you know how the notes were created and use that info to build a test based on specific conditions. If you can control the note creation, I suggest to use a specific form to be able to distinguish each record type.

Of course you can check the properties (fields and values) of your notes and build a test "heuristically" (meaning rule-of-thumb)